# Facebook authentication in Android app

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I'm working on application that is not interacting with Facebook at all.

However - my Android application users will have to login somehow.

I decided to use Facebook authentication mechanism, just to avoid forcing users to create separate accounts on my application server, manage separate passwords etc.

I have found great document about implementing Facebook login in Android application: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate).

It starts like this:

> **Login**
>
> This tutorial walks you through how to add Facebook login to your app
>   with the Facebook SDK for Android. Once you're done following these
>   steps, your app will be able to authenticate people using it with the
>   Facebook Login flow.
>
> We'll introduce you to one of the Facebook SDK's core objects:
>   Session. This object is used to authorize a person to use your app and
>   manage the Facebook Login flow and the app session. Any Facebook API
>   calls that require authentication need to use a Session instance.
>   While an app can create instances of Session and manage them, the
>   Session class provides helpers to simplify the common scenario of an
>   app having one logged-in person at a time.

But I'm not sure if this is right thing to use in my case. I don't want to install/use big Facebook SDK for just auth mechanism if this is not necessary.

**Should I use this or something else?**

Edit/added later:

Application will be multi-platform - Android, iOS, maybe even Windows Phone in future, so I can't assume every user has Google accout.

Comment: on android you could use the google account. most people on android who download your app on the play store will have such an account

Comment: It will be multi-platform (Android/iOS/WinPhone). I can't assume that every user has google account.

Comment: Then you should use the Facebook SDK